# How to move cursor to new_line while reading through UTL file?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

My requirement is to read a file and fetch some data from each line.
for eg:suppose my file conatain this data:

```
a b c d
e f g h
```

I want to read a b c, after reading a b c ,i want to directly move to second line to read e.
Is there is any function to get cursor to starting of next line from current line(imagine cursor position is at middle of the current line and i need to jump directly to initial of next line "to e  here").

Please let me know!!

Answer (score 1):

UTL_FILE.GET_LINE reads data from the file one line at a time.  So the first time called it would read the line 'a b c d', the second time 'e f g h'.  I don't know what you mean by saying your "cursor position is at the middle of the current line".  Can you post your code so far?

Comment: +1. Using `GET_LINE` effectively means the "cursor" is *always* at the start of a line.

Comment: My requirement is to read till c then move the cursor to the start of next line,if i will do get line d will be fecthed also .that i dont want i directly want to move to next line starting.

Comment: You can't.  You must read the whole line, which will include 'd'.  Then parse it in your own code to remove the 'd'.  UTL_FILE does not examine the contents of the lines it reads, it just returns you whole lines.

Answer (score 1):

after reading a line with get_line, use instr and substr to get only a b c and then go to next line.